Single pipeline to interact with multiple repositories without using webhooks
We have a pretty standard requirement, with some twists that puzzle me as a complete devops newbie.

We want a Jenkins job that will detect merge requests against certain branches, fetch the code, build it, if any errors -> report the result and set the merge request status to failed. If no errors, report success and it's all good.
^ I DON'T necessarily need help with this part (because it's a very common scenario and I can find material)

I have 2 constraints that make my requirements different than the norm.
Constraint 1: Our gitlab server cannot connect to our Jenkins server (for IT reasons). This is not negotiable. So I will need to do everything by calling gitlab from Jenkins via gitlab api.
Constraint 2: We want to have a single job (or a single linear series of jobs) for all of our repositories (potentially 30 or more in the future). The repositories are pretty similar to each other.
With these constraints, the job will perform the build checks described earlier.

All of that said, I will describe my current plan. Please tell me if my plan sounds good or if I'm missing something, and if I'm totally off-mark, please point me in the right direction!
I will create 2 jobs.

"event-polling"(?)
build-validator.

The build-validator is the core operation. It will have a parameter for the repository url and another parameter for some kind of "merge request identifier", and it will simply pull that code, perform the checks, and report the results. In other words, it performs the core operation on a single (repository + merge request identifier) unit.
"event-polling" will do the actual detection and filtering. It will run every minute and go through a pre-determined list of repositories by polling them one by one for the events we care about. While doing that, it will create a list of items that look like (repository, merge request identifier) that do have the event we care about and that need build validations. (Let's say 7 repos out of 30 had the event, so we have 7 items.) It will then "call" (or trigger) the build-validator job 7 times, 1 per item, in quick succession.
Jenkins will schedule those 7 build-validator instances and run them when it can, and we'll be good.
Thank you for reading. Appreciate any comments or advice.
